# Unable to verify Cognito JWT token in node/express

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, middleware, pem

**auth.middelware.js**

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const jwkToPem = require("jwk-to-pem");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

let pems = {};                               // <########### pems object initialization and at some point in time, it get undefined

class AuthMiddleWare {

  constructor() {
    this.setUp();
  }

  verifyToken(req, res, next) {
    const token = req?.headers?.authorization;

    if (!token) {
       console.log("no tken")
    }

    let decodeJWT = jwt.decode(token, { complete: true });

    if (!decodeJWT) {
      console.log("error")
    }

    let kid = decodeJWT.header.kid;
    let pem = pems[kid];                            //%%%%%%% in some case pems become undefined automatically

    if (!pem) {                                     
      console.log("No PEM found")                   // <######## since there is no pem, it logs this error msg.
    }

    jwt.verify(token, pem, (err, decodedToken) => {
      if (err) {
       console.log("error occurred while verifying token", err);
      }
      next();
    });
  }

  async setUp() {
    const URL = `https://cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/{environment.POOL_ID}/.well-known/jwks.json`

    try {
      const response = await fetch(URL);

      if (response.status !== 200) {
        throw new Error("request was not successful");
      }

      const data = await response.json();

      const { keys } = data;

      for (let index = 0; index < keys.length; index++) {
        const key = keys[index];
        const key_id = key.kid;
        const modulus = key.n;
        const exponent = key.e;
        const key_type = key.kty;
        const jwk = { kty: key_type, n: modulus, e: exponent };

        const pem = jwkToPem(jwk);

        pems[key_id] = pem;                   // <###### This store two keys/pems in pems object
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("sorry couldn't fetch JWT", error);

    }
  }
};


module.exports = AuthMiddleWare;
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const AuthMiddleWare = require("../auth.middleware");
...
...
...

const auth = new AuthMiddleWare();                // initialize auth class so it will fetch PEMs


// routes are defined below

app.use(`api/products`, auth.verifyToken, productsRoute);    // auth.verifyToken
app.use(`api/customers`, auth.verifyToken, customerRoute);   // auth.verifyToken
...
...
...

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`node-express server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on ${PORT}`);
});
```

My Problem:

When I run my node/express app, it `initializes` auth class and runs `setUp` function and fills `pems ={}` object with two `kid` or `key`;

So at this time `pems` object is not empty and contains two properties (key as property).

Now, through my app, when different APIs (almost 6-7 APIs are being called) simultaneously, randomly, at some point of time, `pems` object get undefined.

Now as you can see in above code, each api uses auth middleware `auth.verifyToken` so even when right token is being passed but since `pems` object becomes undefined (**don't know why it becomes undefined**), it stops my app.

**NOTE:** it happens randomly. It fails for any api. There is no way you can reproduce this issue same way again n again. `pems` gets undefined at random time and it is really hard to debug it.

**Question**
How can I make sure that `pems` object doesn't get undefined?

Or if any better approach is there then you can suggest.